# Hom of Nuclear spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products, nuclear-spaces

1. Let V be a Nuclear space (not necessary Frechet, but complete). Let V^*  be the dual space considered with the weak topology (i.e. pointwise convergence). Is it true that $V^*$ is also nuclear?
2. Is it true that the map to the double dual $V \to V^{**}$ is a linear isomorphism (not necessary continuously invertible)?
3. Let $W$ be a space like $V$. Is the map $V^* \hat \otimes W \to Hom(V,W)$  is a linear isomorphism?
   Here  $V^* \hat{ \otimes} W $ is the completed tensor product and $Hom(V,W)$ is the space of continuous linear maps.
   If yes what topology does it induce on $Hom(V,W)$?
   If not what are the kernel and the image of this map?
4. The same questions for different kinds of duals.

Comment: Many of your questions are answered in Section 10a of the book by Kevin Costello and Owen Gwilliam “Factorization algebras in perturbative quantum field theory” (http://math.northwestern.edu/~costello/factorization_public.html)

Comment: The paper by Costello and Gwilliam was not found at that link.